# Undefined index on $_POST variable sent by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have read similar questions but I didn't find anything useful for me.

I have to ask the user for a message, send it to the server, save it in a database and show it under the input field. I don't want to reload the page, so i used Ajax to send the message. Here is the HTML code

```
<input id="msg" placeholder="Type your message here" onkeyup="detect(event);">
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
var ajax_msg = "Default";  
var ajax_num = -1;         
var ajax_req;              

function detect(key){
    var unicode=key.keyCode? key.keyCode : key.charCode;
    if(unicode == 13) {ajax_call();}
} 

function ajax_call(){
    ajax_msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;

    ajax_req = CreateXmlHttpReq(response_handler); //Create the ajax object and set the onreadystatechange handler
    ajax_req.open("POST","ajaxScript.php", true); 
    var values_string = "msg=" + ajax_msg;
    ajax_req.send(values_string);
}
```

And this is the ajaxScript.php file

```
<?php session_start();
    include "../script.php";

    $conn = db_connection(); //connect to the db
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    save_msg_into_db($msg); //save the message into the db
    close_connection($conn); //close db connection
?>
```

I get this notice: Undefined index: msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavoro\Pagina\ajaxScript.php on line 7

What can I do?

Comment: Make sure you really are using POST and verify your JavaScript really is sending that parameter

Comment: Have you looked at the request in the Network tab of the developer tools in your browser to make sure it is getting sent? And have you also dumped the $_POST array to see what it has set?

Comment: I took a look at the header tab in the chrome developer tools. Everything seems ok, the request is sent using POST and contains the message typed into the field. I used print_r($_POST); obtaining that the array is empty. Also the mysql INSERT query works, but saves an empty message. Everything works, but php does not know the 'msg' index

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of the request from the Network tab?

Answer (score 0):

there are many problems with the objects created from raw javascript way (according to different versions and browsers) to get out of it is better to use a library like jQuery, trying [jquery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)